How to ensure a unique set of dictionary values in Python by removing duplicate values?
I have a dictionary in Python where some values are repeated across different keys. I want to remove the key-value pairs with duplicate values while keeping the first occurrence. Here's an example of my dictionary:
my_dict = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 1,
    'd': 3
}

I want the output to be:
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'd': 3
}

How can I achieve this? What is the most efficient way to do this in Python?

This question is similar to: Removing Duplicates From Dictionary. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since dicts would inherently deduplicate keys, and all the values in your input dict are hashable, you can effectively deduplicate values by making an intermediary dict with values as keys and keys as values. Use the dict.setdefault method to keep only the value of the first occurrence of each distinct key, and then create the final dict from the intermediary dict with key and values swapped back:
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 3}
value_keys = {}
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    value_keys.setdefault(value, key)
print(dict(map(reversed, value_keys.items())))

This outputs:
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 3}

Demo: https://ideone.com/YQ5WLp

Why involve dict.setdefault ?

It's the easiest and most efficient way Python offers to keep the value of the first occurrence of each distinct key.

Still dont get it. Order is stable in dicts since 3.7 (or 3.8) if I am not wrong.

Yes, both the question and this answer are based on the knowledge that dict keys follow insertion order since Python 3.7. If you don't use dict.setdefault you would have to write your own if condition, which comes with a much higher bytecode overhead. You're welcome to try writing one and comparing the performance yourself.

Still dont get it. How is dict(map(reversed, my_dict.items())) insufficient ?

That keeps the value of the last occurrence of each distinct key. Please try it out yourself.

No no you are right. 3am here.


I want to remove the key-value pairs with duplicate values while
keeping the first occurrence


Using setdefault() method.

No need to builtin map() and reverse().
A simpler method to accomplish this:
Snippet:
my_dict =  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 3} 
res = {}
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    res.setdefault(val, key)

print(dict((v, k) for k, v in res.items()))

Output:
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 3}


If you want only the first occurrence of each value be kept, then you can do this:
my_dict = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 1,
    'd': 3
}

seen = set()
result = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v not in seen and not seen.add(v)}

print(result)

Output:
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'd': 3}

The code does the work with a time complexity of O(n)
